# Spring MVC : Expire privilege flag after 5 minutes for edit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

- I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I would I would
  like to give user privilege to edit inside a modal only for 5
  minutes. I have set up a boolean flag for this purpose, so if
  multiple people want to edit this field, then they can read someone
  is editing it, and will edit at their own risk.

  - But my problem is if the first user losses power or gets
    disconnected, I would like to set in database again that the note is
    editable, by making status false. So, I want to allow the Edit flag
    for 5 minutes, then deactivate it. How can I achieve this? Here is my
    code

:

```
  @Override
        public void setActiveEdit(int noteId, boolean status) {
            GroupNotes groupNotes = this.groupNotesDAO.getGroupNoteById(noteId);
    // Start a 5 minutes counter here if status is true
            groupNotes.setActiveEdit(status);
            this.groupNotesDAO.editGroupNote(groupNotes,groupNotes.getOwnednotes().getMsectionid());
        }
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer number two:

```
// in the controller where this stuff is needed
private Map<String, Date> editLocks = new HashMap<>();
private Object concurrencyLock = new Object();


// function for acquiring a lock
private boolean getLock(String id) {
    synchronized(concurrencyLock) {
        Date lastLock = editLocks.get(id);
        if (lastLock == null || longAgoEnough(lastLock)) {
            // add a new lock to the map with the time of now
            editLocks.put(id, now());
            return true; // a lock was available
        }
    }
    // we get here because there's a valid lock
    return false;
}

private void releaseLock(String id) {
    synchronized(concurrencyLock) {
        editLocks.remove(id);
    }
}
```

You'll have to add a bit to this to finish it off, but it would work on a single server pretty well.

Comment: I will try this out, but it looks like this will suffice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about keeping track of a "last lock requested" time?  You could keep track of when the last lock was issued and update it whenever a new lock is requested.

Comment: I want to expire the lock in 5 minutes. So if user losses power or internet connection, then a notice is not shown to other users that the note is being edited.

Comment: If a lock is issued to user 1 and that user loses power a minute later, when user 2 loads the page the lock will indicate that it's still assigned to user 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a scheduled task run every 5 minutes or so that clears any orphaned edits. Use @Scheduled annotation on a method to do this (along with http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Comment: I am aware of Scheduling, but I don't know how to customize it for this specific problem as I need to start the method only when flag is first enabled and only once on a specific note.

Comment: Mix it in with the previous suggestion of having a time-stamp for when the lock was issued. Then your schedule can collect all those locks which are too old to still be valid.

Comment: This would mean storing the timestamps and id's in another database table and running a scheduler, lets say, every 5 minutes, then checking if any of them have expired. Is there any simple way I can trigger a scheduler event exactly after 5 minutes when I set the flag???

Comment: Is this only ever going to run on a single server? If so, then you could do something way simpler. You could just store the locks in a Set or HashMap (you'd have to protect this from multi-threading). Then when someone wants a lock you either check to see if there's not one, or if there is one and it's out of date.

Comment: It is a single server, I will try this out, but if you have any similar code, please feel free to give it paste it in your answer.